# Stop spacebar from scrolling page

Tags: events, jquery, preventdefault

I know that `e.preventDefault();` is supposed to stop the spacebar from scrolling on the page, but it is not working on my function

```
$("html").live("keyup", function (e) {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if ((code == 32 || code == 13) && $("span").is(":focus")) {
        openDropdown();
        $(".dropdown a.PivotItem:first").focus();
        e.preventDefault();
    } else if ((code == 32 || code == 13) && $("a.PivotItem").is(":focus")) {
        closeDropdown();
        changeSelected($("*:focus"));
        e.preventDefault();
    } else if (code == 27 && ($("span").is(":focus") || $(".dropdown a.PivotItem").is(":focus"))) {
        closeDropdown();
        $("span").focus();
    } else {
        //do nothing
    }
});
```

Does it have something to do with the `.live(` handler I have included?

Comment: Do your other keys do what's expected? In a very quick test in Chrome, the scroll happens on key down, rather than key up, so you may be trying to capture the key press too late

Comment: @Purmou I'm not changing default behaviors in this function, I am adding accessibility to traversing the navigation with the keyboard.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The space-bar scrolls the page on `keydown`, not on `keyup`, so try:

```
$("html").on("keydown", function (e) {
   // etc
```

You don't really need to use `.live()`, because the `html` element will exist when your code runs.

Also, jQuery normalises `event.which` so you don't need to test for `event.keyCode`.

Comment: So my code doesn't work because I am preventing the default event of the space bar on keyup, which happens to be nothing.  Weird, thanks!